# Custom web address in force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites, custom-url

I'm setting up an integration in which the an external system make a request to SF, SF processes the request and returns the information in json.

Right now, I have a simple endpoint to which the external system makes the request and the URL is something like this:

**http://mydomain.cs18.force.com/mysite?param1=param1&param2=param2**

and I want for the URL to look like this:

**http://mysite.com/api/v1/something.json?param1=param1&param2=param2**

Is this possible? I tried adding a custom URL to my force.com site, but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

eclf

Answer (score 2):

1. register a new custom domain via Setup -> Domain Management -> Domains. There you can add a custom domain after you added a CNAME record to your DNS.
2. Associate your domain and your site via Setup -> Domain management -> Custom URLs

Now you are able to access to public SFDC site!

Please make sure that you are using your prod. environment. Custom domains are not available in sandbox organizations.

To access your rest service you have prefix the request url with `/services/apexrest`

Comment: Yeah, I've never done this ("... after you added a CNAME record to your DNS") before, so I need to do some investigating. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: You need access to your DNS server. There you can specify DNS-Records and CName records.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using the sites functionality in Salesforce?

I've not done this personally although I have looked into before but you can mask the Salesforce site URL if you have access to modify the CNAME record for your domain. The Salesforce help article is:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_domains.htm&language=en_US